# Tools to visualize adhoc multi dimentional data

Tags: ssms, ssas, mdx

With SSMS I cannot run a MDX query such as

```
Select [Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount] on 0,
[Product].[Category].children on 1,
Product.[Model Name].children on 2
From [Adventure Works];
```

since it supports only 2 axes and hence gives the error message

```
Results cannot be displayed for cellsets with more than two axes.
```

However SSAS itself supports 128 axes I believe.

What can I use to run ad hoc queries against SSAS with more than 2 axes?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve with more than two axes? If at the end you just want those fields/values to be dumped into a tabular result, you can rewrite your query to use crossjoins.

```
Select [Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount] on 0,
{[Product].[Category].children * Product.[Model Name].children} on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Yes, that is a valid workaround, but instead of dumping the data to a single tabular result, I wanted to be able to explore the dimensions, like have each model name on  a separate page with the category wise results on the page

Comment: SSMS isn't really a data exploration or visualization tool. I suggest you look into those type of solutions. You can make tables paged/grouped by category in SSRS or Tableau or many other data viz tools. So basically, it isn't about how you write your query, but how you visualize the resulting data.

Comment: Right..  but SSRS doesnt support ad hoc queries, dont know about tableau , my point was, since SSAS allows me to specify a pages axis (as an example), is there a tool that will show the output in a way that the pages axis actually appears on different pages? But one where I write ad hoc queries and dont actually design reports